# 2D Array - Does not updating quantity as i want

Tags: arrays, session, asp-classic, multidimensional-array

I got a shopping cart code that using a 2D Array to store user order in a Session!
We have some const here:

```
CONST CART_Product_ID = 0
CONST CART_Product_NAME = 1
CONST CART_Product_PRICE = 0
CONST CART_Product_QUANTITY = 3
```

My first question is here!!
why these constants defined? and why got value 0-1-0-3 ?!

in next step it get variables from a form like this:

```
Dim Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Price, Product_Qty
Product_ID      = trim(request("pro_id"))  
Product_Name    = trim(request("pro_name"))  
Product_Price   = trim(request("pro_price"))
Product_Qty     = trim(request("pro_qty"))
```

and in next step, it check out that there is a session and if not create one:

```
If not isArray(Session("Cart")) then  
    dim localCart(4,50)
ELSE  
    localCart = Session("Cart")  
End If
```

in next step it check the array to Add or update quantity of item like this:

```
Dim FoundIt, i
if Product_ID <> "" then
    FoundIt = False
    For i = 0 to ubound(localCart)
        If localCart(CART_Product_ID,i) = Product_ID then
            localCart(CART_Product_QUANTITY,i) = localCart(CART_Product_QUANTITY,i)+1
            FoundIt = true
            EXIT For
        End If
    NEXT
    If NOT FoundIt then
        For i = 0 to ubound(localCart,2)
            If localCart(CART_Product_ID,i) = "" Then
                localCart(CART_Product_ID,i) = Product_ID
                localCart(CART_Product_NAME,i) = Product_Name
                localCart(CART_Product_PRICE,i) = Product_Price
                localCart(CART_Product_QUANTITY,i) = Product_Qty
                EXIT For
            End If
        NEXT
    End If
End If

Session("Cart") = localCart
```

And some problems is here!!
1- when i post a same product to this page ( product_ID=1), it add more and more instead of updating the Quantity, Why?!

2-when i want to write content of array like this:

```
Dim OrderTotal
OrderTotal = 0
for i = 0 to ubound(localCart,2)
   if localCart(CART_Product_ID, i) <> "" then
      orderTotal = orderTotal + (localCart(CART_Product_PRICE,i)) * localCart(CART_Product_QUANTITY,i)
      Response.Write("Product ID = "& localCart(CART_Product_ID,i) &"<br/>")
      Response.Write("Product Name = "& localCart(CART_Product_NAME,i) &"<br/>")
      Response.Write("Product Price = "& localCart(CART_Product_PRICE,i) &"<br/>")
      Response.Write("Product Qty= "& localCart(CART_Product_QUANTITY,i) &"<br/>")
   end if
next
Response.Write ("Total = "& formatCurrency(orderTotal) &"")
```

It instead of price, show me the product id!!
oupput is like this:

Product ID = 1
Product Name = Cheese
Product Price = 1 !!!!!!!
Product Qty = 1

Please guide me! :(

Comment: What happens when you change CART_Product_PRICE = 2?

Comment: Looks like you got some bad code.

Comment: yeah ;) stark do you have an idea about counting the items, i want to show it to users! do you have an idea? :)

Comment: @stark, care to turn your comment into an answer so that OP can accept that?

Answer (score 0):

Not a great design.  The four constants act as a table index so they need to be four distinct values.

```
CONST CART_Product_ID = 0
CONST CART_Product_NAME = 1
CONST CART_Product_PRICE = 2    <= this one was wrong
CONST CART_Product_QUANTITY = 3
```